# unexpected closing tag angular error

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Writing an angular app in bulma, copied the template directly from the template site for testing and I get this error. I have checked and checked and everything is closed properly, yet somehow I keep getting an unclosed nav error. Oddly enough when I delete the closing nav tag, the site compiles correctly, but is broken. I have no idea what to do.

Code

```
<section class="hero is-info is-fullheight">
<div class="hero-head">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a class="navbar-item" href="../">
          <img src="http://bulma.io/images/bulma-type-white.png" alt="Logo">
        </a>
        <span class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="navbarMenu">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div id="navbarMenu" class="navbar-menu">
          <div class="navbar-end">
                       <span class="navbar-item">
            <a class="button is-white is-outlined" href="#">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
              </span>
              <span>Home</span>
            </a>
          </span>
                       <span class="navbar-item">
            <a class="button is-white is-outlined" href="#">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-superpowers"></i>
              </span>
              <span>Examples</span>
            </a>
          </span>
          <span class="navbar-item">
            <a class="button is-white is-outlined" href="#">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
              </span>
              <span>Documentation</span>
            </a>
          </span>
          <span class="navbar-item">
            <a class="button is-white is-outlined" href="https://github.com/dansup/bulma-templates/blob/master/templates/landing.html">
              <span class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-github"></i>
              </span>
              <span>View Source</span>
            </a>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="hero-body">
  <div class="container has-text-centered">
    <div class="column is-6 is-offset-3">
      <h1 class="title">
        Coming Soon
      </h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle">
         $this is the best software platform for running an internet business. We handle billions of dollars every year for forward-thinking businesses around the world.
      </h2>
      <div class="box">

        <div class="field is-grouped">
          <p class="control is-expanded">
            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email">
          </p>
          <p class="control">
            <a class="button is-info">
              Notify Me
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Error

```
`compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
   Unexpected closing tag "nav". It may happen when the tag has already 
   been closed by another tag. For more info see 
   https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have- 
   implied-end-tags ("
          </div>
        </div>
      [ERROR ->]</nav>
    </div>`
```

Comment: Run your code through any HTML validator. Your div#container has not been properly closed: re-check your indentation.

Answer (score 4):

Usually if you see an "Unexpected closing tag `<something>`" the problem isn't actually with that `<something>` but rather with an adjacent element that hasn't been properly closed. Paste stuff here: https://validator.w3.org or any similar HTML validator service, or use a better editor/IDE that offers syntax highlighting to help you find these errors.

You are missing a closing `</div>` tag.
You close `navbar-brand`, `navbar-menu` and `navbar-end` but you do not close `<div class='container'>`

As this missing `</div>` tag ought to be directly *before* `</nav>`, you get the error telling you, in fact, exactly where you ought to look. "I found a `</nav>` I wasn't expecting to see!" ... Ok, so go look at wherever you have a `</nav>` and figure out what element nearby is missing or has typos, etc.

Answer (score 4):

in my case I was forgetting a detail in the tag

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click) "handleClickMe()
    ">Click me !</button>
```

I forgot to put the "=" in `(click)="handleClickMe()`

Comment: for me, I forgot the closing `"`

Answer (score 2):

Adding for future reference, for Angular

I've also seen this where you have invalid html like this

```
<p>
  <div>
  </div>
</p>
```

Change the p to a div and it'll work